# StringBuilder append in for loop in Java

Tags: java, for-loop, stringbuilder

When I execute the following:

```
static void Append() {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    System.out.print("How many words do you want to append? ");
    int n = input.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Please type the words you want to append: ");
    for (int c = 1; c <= n; c++) {
        String str = input.nextLine();
        sb.append(str);
        System.out.print(" ");
    }
    System.out.print(sb);

}
```

Let's say if I put 3, then the computer lets me type only 2 words..

This is the output:

```
How many words do you want to append? 3
Please type the words you want to append: 
 I
 am
 Iam
```

Also, why is there a space before the words? the print function is after the input function. So shouldn't it be the opposite?

Comment: where is `input` defined?

Comment: Input is defined as the static field in the same class. I know Scanner#nextLine consumes line separators so i inserted println after nextInt, but still no difference

Comment: add `input.nextLine();` after the line  `int n = input.nextInt();` should work

Comment: Oh my, i was inserting println the whole time, my intention was nextline..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you debug that program, you can find that the first time of loop will get `input.nextLine()` with an empty string. This is when the problem occurs.

When you input a `3` and a `\n` for `int n = input.nextInt();`, the input buffer contains "3\n", and `input.nextInt();` will just take that "3", like the image below:

[image: the position is 1]
where the `position` of input is 1, remaining the "\n" in the buffer. Then when the program required for `nextLine()`, it will read the buffer until a "\n", which results in reading an empty string.

[image: the position changed to 2 after a nextLine()]

So a possible workaround is to add a `String empty = input.nextLine();` before the loop, or use `input.next();` instead of `input.nextLine();`, since in the document says, `input.next();` will return the next token.

**Update:** Notice that no one answers your second question in the bottom...

You should modify the line `System.out.println(" ");` in the loop into `sb.append(" ");`.

Comment: Thats what i exactly thought. So i inserted nextline after nextInt but still let me only 2 words if i type 3

Comment: @KeKe I also tried add a `String empty = input.nextLine();` before the loop, and it is showing the expected result for me. Is your program didn't be recompiled?

Comment: Nope i was dumb. I was inserting PRINTLN the whole time when i intended to insert nextLine lmao. Thanks for answering this dumb question!

Comment: I updated the answer about your question in the bottom.

Answer (score 1):

You should replace nextLine() by next().

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Main
{
static void Append() {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
System.out.print("How many words do you want to append? ");
int n = input.nextInt();
System.out.println("Please type the words you want to append: ");
String str = null;
for (int c = 0; c < n; c++) {
     str = input.next();
    sb.append(str +" " );

}
System.out.print(sb);
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Hello World");
    Append();
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it is because it read a line changing char into the string
so it consider the changing line as the first and the first string is taken.
you could only have two string to input

Answer (score 0):

If you put code printing line which was read from input as follows:

```
static void append() {
  Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
  System.out.print("How many words do you want to append? ");
  int n = input.nextInt();
  System.out.println("Please type the words you want to append: ");

  for (int c = 1; c <= n; c++) {
    String str = input.nextLine();
    System.out.println("input str=" + str); //pay attention to this line
    sb.append(str);
    System.out.print(" ");
  }
  System.out.print(sb);
}
```

you will see that first iteration does not read from input. Because there is already `\n` in buffer which was read with nextInt.

To solve that you can skip line after nextInt as in code bellow (I am not sure that it is best solution):

```
static void append() {
  Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
  System.out.print("How many words do you want to append? ");
  int n = input.nextInt();
  System.out.println("Please type the words you want to append: ");

  if (input.hasNextLine()) input.nextLine();

  for (int c = 1; c <= n; c++) {
    String str = input.nextLine();
    System.out.println("input str=" + str);
    sb.append(str);
    System.out.print(" ");
  }
  System.out.print(sb);
}
```

Using next() is not solution, if you want read sentences as single string.